# How to swipe specific element using appium?

Tags: c#, android, appium

I have list of elements of specific type, I want to swipe one of this element right or left, How i can do this using appium ? 
 
I know i can use `driver.Swipe();` to swipe in appium but how to use to swipe specific element ?
My list of elements is 
`var contacts = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("android.widget.ImageView"));
contacts[7].Click();` 
How can I swipe element `contacts[7]` to right or left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is taken from the test suite for the Appium C# bindings.
Basically, you use the element's coordinates as a starting point for the swipe.
The only thing you need to know is the target coordinates for the swipe. Of course, if you just want to swipe in a specific direction you can hardcode the coordinates.

```
[Test ()]
public void ComplexTouchActionTestCase ()
{
    IList<AppiumWebElement> els = driver.FindElementsByClassName ("android.widget.TextView");
    var loc1 = els [7].Location;
    AppiumWebElement target = els[1];
    var loc2 = target.Location;
    driver.Swipe (loc1.X, loc1.Y, loc2.X, loc2.Y, 800); //this action includes almost all touch actions
    Assert.AreNotEqual(loc2.Y, target.Location.Y);
}
```